# Android - ViewPager and ViewFlipper overlap issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewflipper, overlap

I want to implement something using **ViewPager** to slide the tutorial pages in front and at the same time using **ViewFlipper** to flip the background pages. That means ViewPager and ViewFlipper are to be overlap. So when I separately write two class for implementing **GestureDetector** to write them, only the ViewPager can flip and the ViewFlipper did not work. How can I modify this so that both ViewPager and ViewFlipper can flip at same time?

Or if there is another way to implement something like, Some tutorial pages flips in the front and Background pages with different animations also flipping at some time?

Comment: how abt you implement gesture detector foe either one and based on the user action, you do the code to flip the other one? Like, implement gesture detector for ViewPager and from the callback you flip the viewflipper thru code

Comment: I agree. Can you tell me more detail how to callback action from one view to anther? Thank you very much..